# "n Answers;" below the question, is ";" symbol intended?

Tags: bug

Take any question, for example this one:

[How do I detect a null reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202630/how-do-i-detect-a-null-reference-in-c)

Right below the question it has

## 9 Answers<sup>**;**</sup>

Note the `;` sign ↑. Is it supposed to be that way?